# Silverlight 4 Tooltip Visibility Binding

Tags: binding, tooltip, visibility

I'm trying to bind tooltip visibility in XAML and I'm running into a confusing problem where my visibility binding works fine on other controls but not on the tooltip.

I have a form with a submit button that is disabled when the required fields haven't been entered.  When the button is disabled I want a tooltip on it with a relevant message.  When it's enabled there is no need for the tooltip.  To accomplish this I place the button in a transparent border and set the tooltip on the border since a tooltip on the button itself will never show when it's disabled.  However, visibility binding to the tooltip fails and it seems I can only change the visibility in code-behind.  I can use the exact same binding on visibility for various controls (in the example below I use it on a TextBlock as well).  If I apply the exact same binding in code-behind, it works fine.  Why doesn't this work in XAML?

**XAML**

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:VisibilityConverter x:Key="visibilityConverter"/>
    <local:VisibilityConverter x:Key="reversedVisibilityConverter" IsReversed="True"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<StackPanel Background="White"
            Width="310">
    <TextBlock Text="Using XAML binding for tooltip visibility..."
               FontWeight="Bold"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="cbEnable"
              Content="Enable Submit Button"/>
    <Border Background="Transparent"
            Margin="0,10,0,0">
        <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
            <!-- This has the same binding as the 2nd TextBlock below, it should be visible when cbEnable is NOT checked and collapsed when it is checked -->
            <ToolTip Content="Submit Button Is Disabled"
                     Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=cbEnable, Converter={StaticResource reversedVisibilityConverter}}"/>
        </ToolTipService.ToolTip>

        <Button Content="Submit"
                IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=cbEnable}"/>
    </Border>

    <!-- This TextBlock is visibile when cbEnable is checked -->
    <TextBlock Text="Submit Button is enabled"
               Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=cbEnable, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}"/>
    <!-- This TextBlock is visibile when cbEnable is NOT checked (same as ToolTip binding above -->
    <TextBlock Text="Submit Button is disabled"
               Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=cbEnable, Converter={StaticResource reversedVisibilityConverter}}"/>

    <TextBlock Text="Using code-behind binding for tooltip visibility..."
               FontWeight="Bold"
               Margin="0,20,0,0"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="cbEnable2"
              Content="Enable Submit Button"/>

    <Border Background="Transparent"
            Margin="0,10,0,0">
        <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
            <ToolTip x:Name="toolTip2"
                     Content="Submit Button 2 Is Disabled"/>
        </ToolTipService.ToolTip>

        <Button Content="Submit 2"
                IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=cbEnable2}"/>
    </Border>

    <TextBlock Text="Submit Button 2 is enabled"
               Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=cbEnable2, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Submit Button 2 is disabled"
               Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=cbEnable2, Converter={StaticResource reversedVisibilityConverter}}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl {
    public MainPage() {
        InitializeComponent();

        toolTip2.SetBinding(ToolTip.VisibilityProperty, new System.Windows.Data.Binding("IsChecked") {
            Source = cbEnable2,
            Converter = new VisibilityConverter() { IsReversed = true }
        });
    }
}
```

**VisibilityConverter:**

```
public class VisibilityConverter : IValueConverter {
    public bool IsReversed { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        bool isVisible = System.Convert.ToBoolean(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        if (IsReversed) {
            isVisible = !isVisible;
        }
        return (isVisible ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        bool isVisible = ((Visibility)value == Visibility.Visible);
        if (IsReversed) {
            isVisible = !isVisible;
        }
        return isVisible;
    }
}
```

Comment: After further testing, it seems impossible to bind Visibility of a Tooltip in XAML, although binding is code-behind works perfectly well.  Is this a bug or an architectural limitation?  Any ideas?

Comment: good question. i learned how to set Visibility from codebehind. my vote +1

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know why this fixed it but here is what I did: I renamed the property in my ViewModel. Yep, I know. Seems ridiculous. I changed the property from IsWaitingVisible to WaitingVisibility. I got the idea because I changed the ViewModel property from a bool to text and then bound it to a temporary, visible TextBlock. It would not show the value the same way a different property in the same ViewModel would. That was just crazy so I renamed the property to something else and voila! The text started appearing in the UI. Then, I reconnected the visibility property of the grid (and changed my VisibilityConverter to work with strings instead of bool) and everything worked.

I guess for the purposes of science, I should change the property name back to IsWaitingVisible and see if it breaks. If so, I will have to conclude that this is a hard bug in SL 5.

This kind of flakiness just scares me when I think about building reliable apps in Silverlight.